# how to convert a date in GMT format to another format?

Tags: android, date, time, type-conversion

How can i convert Fri Dec 29 05:30:00 GMT 05:30 20 into 29-12-2017 02:28:03 this format in android.i already used the below code  for convert the date but i can't work.so please help me out.

```
String date =  Fri Dec 29 05:30:00 GMT 05:30 20

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy h:mm:ss");

Date date1 = sdf.parse(date);
```

Comment: which field in GMT format is year?

Answer (score 0):

Below two methods to convert date as per your requirement

//method for converting TimeStamp date(long) to String... in Date

```
public static String makeLongTODate(long dateTime) {
    Date d = new Date(dateTime);
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
    String date = simpleDateFormat.format(d);
    return date;
}

//method for converting TimeStamp date(long) to String... in date & Time
public static String makeLongTODateTime(long dateTime) {
    Date d = new Date(dateTime);
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
    String date = simpleDateFormat.format(d);
    return date;
}
```

Comment: can i convert one date formate to another date formate in android?

Comment: yes while retrieving data in JSON.. You might be using Retrofit or Volley... JSON provide the date in TimeStamp format or in long.. you can convert it into String or in date format... you can use parse method to convert it.. or can use format to convert in String Date..use above method in android to convert